# how to subscribe a list of phone numbers to a aws-sns topic

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I need to send 200 sms messages, and looking in the amazon documentation I found how to do this by subscribing to a topic but only one by one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();
  String phoneNumber = "+1XXX5550100";
  String topicArn = createSNSTopic(snsClient);
  subscribeToTopic(snsClient, topicArn, "sms", phoneNumber);
}


public static void subscribeToTopic(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String topicArn, 
        String protocol, String endpoint) { 
        SubscribeRequest subscribe = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, protocol,
                                                          endpoint);
        SubscribeResult subscribeResult = snsClient.subscribe(subscribe);
}
```

Is there any way I send a list of phone numbers to the endpoint, or I subscribe a list of SubscribeRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you *cannot* pass a *`list of phone numbers`* as an endpoint when you create subscription for a SNS Topic. Each subscription can have only *`ONE`* phone number as an endpoint.

For emails, we can just provide the group email-id, and the email server will handle the distribution list. But something similar is not possible for phone numbers. *`As far as SNS is concerned, it needs a single endpoint for a selected protocol(SMS/EMAIL)`*.

Just to simplify things, what you do is you can maintain a list for the phone numbers in your code. You can loop through the list and call the `subscribeToTopic` method each time with the *`same topic ARN but different phone number`*. But I am sure you would have thought about this yourself.

Comment: thx man, i did the loop but i thought that should have a better way ... Could you give me an example of the e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

We can pass a list of phone numbers to an endpoint using AWS SDKs.

If you need to send messages to multiple recipients, it's worthwhile to read though Amazon's docs: (https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-topic.html) on sending to multiple phone numbers.

The SNS service implements the Publish-Subscribe pattern, and you can use it to send messages to a topic. Here are the steps to make this work:

1. Create a named topic. This is just a communication channel to which you can subscribe phone numbers.
2. Subscribe your recipients to the topic.
3. Publish a message on the topic.

The python code looks something like this:

```
import boto3

# Create an SNS client
client = boto3.client(
    "sns",
    aws_access_key_id="YOUR ACCES KEY",
    aws_secret_access_key="YOUR SECRET KEY",
    region_name=us-east-1
)

# Create the topic if it doesn't exist
topic = client.create_topic(Name="invites-for-push-notifications")
topic_arn = topic['TopicArn']  # get its Amazon Resource Name

#Get List of Contacts
list_of_contacts = ["+919*********", "+917********", "+918********"]

# Add SMS Subscribers
for number in some_list_of_contacts:
    client.subscribe(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Protocol='sms',
        Endpoint=number  # <-- number who'll receive an SMS message.
    )

# Publish a message.
client.publish(Message="Good news everyone!", TopicArn=topic_arn)
```